# Spark Master filling temporary directory

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple Spark app that reads some data, computes some metrics, and then saves the result (input and output are Cassandra table). This piece of code runs at regular intervals (i.e., every minute).

I have a Cassandra/Spark (Spark 1.6.1) and after a few minutes, my temporary directory on the master node of the Spark cluster is filled, and the master refuses to run any more jobs. I am submitting the job with spark-submit.

What is it that I am missing? How do I make sure that the master nodes removes the temporary folder?

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses this directory as the scratch space and outputs temp map output files in there. This can be changed. You should take a look into `spark.local.dir`.

Comment: I have no problem with the workers, it is the master node that is filling the disk. Every iteration of my app is creating a new temporary folder, containing the jar itself, and they are not getting deleted when the job is finished.

Comment: That is correct, usually when spark submit completes the job is does clean up temp files. Which version of spark you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you submit your app, the jar is copied to all the workers in a new app directory. How big is your jar? Are you building a fat jar including the datastax driver jar? In that case I am guessing your app would be a few MB. Running it every minute will fill up your disk very quickly.

Spark has two parameters to control the cleaning of the app directories:
**spark.worker.cleanup.interval** which control how often spark is going to clean
**spark.worker.cleanupDataTtl** which control how long an app directory should stay before being cleaned.

Both parameters are in seconds.

Hope this help!